# How can I use the System.Net namespace into a Visual Studio 2010 c++ project?

Tags: c++, dll, import, namespaces, c++-cli

I'm having troubles to import `System.Net` namespace from .NET into my `C++` project.

I've tried it by using: "using namespace System.Net" but I guess I'd need to import some DLL to my project properties in order to make this statement work. How can I do this? Does someone have any opinion on how to overcome this problem? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming C++/CLI, try System::Net since it is C++ we're talking about here.

Comment: the problem is that it's not able to find the System namespace. I guess I need to add the reference, but in my project properties->Add references, the list is empty

Comment: Added the C++/CLI tag.

Comment: Is your project a CLR project?

Answer (score 6):

In your **C++/CLI** code, you can do:

```
#using <System.dll>

using namespace System::Net;
```

Answer (score 2):

in addition to specifying

using namespace System::Net;

you also need to add a reference to the System.Net assembly...

do the following:

1. Right Click project and choose properties
2. Click the "Common Properties" item in the left tree view
3. Click the "Add New Reference" button
4. In the "Add Reference Dialog", select Assemblies/Framework in the left tree view
5. Find "System.Net" in the list box on the add add it to your project